# How to find largest common subtrees in a multi tree

Tags: java, algorithm, serialization, data-structures, tree

Recently, I encounter a algorithm problem: the tree is defined as

```
public class Node 
{
    int id;      
    private final List<Node> children;
    Node(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
    }      
}
```

> Two subtrees are in common if their structure is identical. The largest common subtrees maximizes the number of nodes in each individual subtrees. So how to find the maxmum common subtree(the id of each node does not matter, just the structure of the subtrees be the same). If there are separate groups of subtrees that are in common with the same maximal size, then we should should return the root nodes from all of the subtrees.

My idea is to serialize each subtree into unique string using BFS. After we get all strings, sort them, and compare which two are equal. So below is my code. My question is because the serialization each subtree cause much overhead, is there any other idea to solve this problem in a better time complexity.

```
public static List<Node> getLargestCommonSubtrees(Node root) {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Node>>();
        LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
        queue.add(root);
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node cur = queue.pollFirst();
            String sig = serialize(cur);
            if (map.containsKey(sig)) {
                ArrayList<Node> list = map.get(sig);
                list.add(cur);
                map.put(sig, list);
            } else {
                ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
                list.add(cur);
                map.put(sig, list);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cur.children.size(); i++) {
                if (cur.children.get(i) != null) {
                    queue.add(cur.children.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        ArrayList<Node> ans = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Node>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().length() >= max) {
                if (e.getKey().length() > max) {
                    ans.clear();
                }
                ans.addAll(e.getValue());
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }

private static String serialize(Node n) {
        String signature = "";
        LinkedList<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
        q.add(n);
        if (n.children.size() == 0) {
            signature = "0";
            return signature;
        }
        Node curr = null;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            curr = q.peek();
            q.poll();
            signature += String.valueOf(curr.children.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < curr.children.size(); i++) {
                q.offer(curr.children.get(i));
            }
        }
        return signature;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JoJo, there might already exist an efficient algorithm out there for this or a similar problem. However, here is how I would do it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Node
{
    //signature = number of Node's children + signature of each child     =  total number of all nodes below this Node (including children and children's children...etc)
    //
    // for example, a tree would have it's signature as
    //             13
    //      1       5        4  
    //      0    1    2    1   1
    //           0   0 0   0   0
    //
    private int signature;

    private int id;      
    private final List<Node> children;
    private Node parent;

    public Node(int id, Node parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    //updates signature, should be called every time there is a change to Node.
    private void updateSignature() {
        signature = children.size();

        for(Node childNode : children) {
            signature += childNode.signature;
        }

        //tell parent to update it's signature
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.updateSignature();
        }
    }

    //compares two trees to check if their structure is similar
    private boolean hasSameStructureAs(Node otherNode) {
        return otherNode != null && signature == otherNode.signature;
    }
}
```